# Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93) while installing node-sass

Tags: node.js, node-sass

I am trying to `yarn install` but keeps getting the following error:

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
```

Full error stack:

```
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:398:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Rahul Sharma\\PycharmProjects\\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass
_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Rahul Sharma\PycharmProjects\Trakkia_Frontend_V2\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
```

earlier the project was running fine. The only change I did was updating the node version form 12 to latest.
How do I resolve this ?

Comment: Try installing `Python 3.7` and try it over again.

Comment: @DavidR I Updated the dependencies with `"node-sass": "^6.0.0",` and it installed but now it says `Error: Node Sass version 6.0.1 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.`

Comment: Okay. Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and delete your `package-lock.json` as well. Then add `"sass-loader": "^11.1.1"` to your `devDependencies` and do an `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the binding for your current environment. You can build it by running the following command:

`npm rebuild node-sass`